# Belking Wireless Router unable to connect to internet although wireless connection is working

Tags: wireless-networking, wireless-router

I have a Belkin Basic N150 Wireless router.

I'm trying to set up wireless connection using the wired ports my university has provided in my hostel room.

Usually, when I connect my laptop using a LAN wire through the port, my settings are like

```
IP:              10.5.130.X
Subnet Mask:     255.255.254.0
Default Gateway: 10.5.130.250
DNS Server:      10.200.1.11
```

and I'm able to connect to the internet.

Now instead of connecting my laptop directly, I've connected the LAN wire to the Belkin wireless router, set the router as "Use as an Access Point" and in the IP field, I've put up `10.5.130.1`.

Now I've set the IP of my system manually to `10.5.130.3`. I'm able to connect to the wi-fi but I'm still not able to connect to the internet.

What am I missing?

Comment: Most universities disallow use of routers in rooms.... However, how does registration on the network work there?  Many are based on login credentials tied with your MAC address, in which case you would need to either spoof the MAC on the router or register it.  Also, I am pretty sure you want Bridged mode rather than AP.

Comment: Once I'm connected to the internet, I just need to use my student username/password (LDAP ID) to login and use the internet. I think it's not based on any specific MAC address as I've tried accessing the internet from multiple devices at the same time.

Comment: Depending on how the DHCP server works, you may not be able to hard-code an IP like that.  How do you know that 10.5.130.1 isn't in use somewhere else on your network?  Does your router not get an IP by itself?  When you log in, do you do it through a captive portal in a web browser?

Comment: If I can't hard-code the IP, what options do I have? The IP I've assigned is free for me as we follow a convention according to our room numbers. The router doesn't get an IP, by default it was 192.168.1.2. For the authentication, the username/password comes up as a system level pop-up, I don't think it is a captive portal as what I understand.

Comment: Try this: plug the router into the wall (using WAN), leave DHCP turned on on your router, and plug the laptop into LAN and let it get an IP from your router.  Then try authenticating.  It may grant an IP to the WAN interface on the router, then anything you connect to the router will be on the router's NAT network and should have internet access.  All depends on exactly how the network is set up though.  As was mentioned before however, you might be violating university rules by doing this, which I don't condone.

Answer (score 1):

Plug the LAN wire in the LAN port of the router (not the WAN one). Disable DHCP on it and it should work. This will transform the router in a switch and most routers I have seen can work this way. As you said you can connect multiple devices at the same time, you can receive multiple IPs and with the router acting as a switch, the devices will have their own DHCP exchange with the DHCP server (and authentication) without interference from the router.

If it doesn't work out of the box, you may have to set the LAN IP of the router to one valid (and free) IP in the subnet you will receive the IP from the DHCP.

Comment: Worked for me on my Belkin AC1200 :)